# How can I download / get WordPress .PO partial strings - Only frontend strings?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to have a .PO file for wooCommerce that ONLY contains the front-end strings! ***and sure I can't determine which the exact strings are used in front-end when open the file to delete them***. Is there a way to do this and get **A READY TRANSLATED** front-end strings from [translation project page](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/) or by any workaround even if complicated?

Need the Arabic front-end strings translated.

Comment: Try to use [LOCO translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) plugin.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Hello, Thank you but I need this .PO for a different usage.

Comment: https://poeditor.com/pricing/ and https://www.g2.com/products/poeditor/competitors/alternatives

Comment: Install EasyPo. Download the pot file , translate what you want and upload the generated po and mo files. Since woo may have translation you need to register your own custom arabic language so you can use your translation bcs woo will overwrite it on next update.